# Black Holes in Horava-Lifshitz Gravity?

Tags: black-holes, quantum-gravity

I know that Cosmology has a role in [Horava-Lifshitz Gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ho%C5%99ava%E2%80%93Lifshitz_gravity), but do Black Holes play a significant role in the applications of Horava Lifshitz Gravity, if so, what will be the mathematical equations describing it?